# Cordova blank page / empty index.html file when running ios app

Tags: ios, cordova, svelte, ionic-webview

I'm building my svelte app.
In the config.xml file, I'm targeting `<content src="./public/index.html" />` which works perfectly on Android.

When I try to launch it on ios:

1. Splash screen shows.
2. Splash screen fades into white.
3. Page is blank and contains:

```
<html><head></head><body></body></html>
```

the console has the following error:
`Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 () - ionic://localhost`

I tried adding:

```
<preference name="Hostname" value="public" />
or
<preference name="Hostname" value="app" />
or
<preference name="Hostname" value="localhost/public" />
```

But to no avail.

I'm using the following versions/dependencies:

```
dependencies:
"cordova": "^11.0.0"
devDependencies:
"cordova-ios": "^6.2.0",
"cordova-plugin-exclude-files": "^1.0.1",
"cordova-plugin-inappbrowser": "^5.0.0",
"cordova-plugin-ionic-webview": "^5.0.0",
"cordova-plugin-splashscreen": "^6.0.1",
"cordova-plugin-whitelist": "^1.3.4"
```

I've got the following Allows/navigations:

```
<access launch-external="yes" origin="mailto:*" />
<platform name="android">
    <allow-intent href="market:*" />
</platform>
<allow-intent href="mailto:*" />
<allow-navigation href="http://*" />
<allow-navigation href="https://*" />
<allow-navigation href="*" />

<access origin="*" />
<allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
<allow-intent href="https://*/*" />

<platform name="android">
    <allow-intent href="market:*" />
</platform>
<platform name="ios">
    <allow-intent href="itms:*" />
    <allow-intent href="itms-apps:*" />
</platform>
```

Running on macOS Monterey - Version 12.3.1

xcode: Version 13.3.1 (13E500a)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is with the UIWebView in the ionic-webview.  It is no longer available in iOS.  You need to switch to capacitor.    Capacitor is using WKWebView.

Comment: You're a life saver! capacitor is awesome. much easier to use / deploy